# Python Pandas print error in Eclipse's PyDev: unknown encoding: MS874

Tags: python, eclipse, pandas, pydev

I am trying to use Pandas library to read csv files, using Eclipse's PyDev.

foo.csv file:

```
"head1", "head2",
"A", "123"
```

test.py:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('foo.csv');
print data
```

I ran this and got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qqq\studyspace\macd\test3.py", line 4, in <module>
    print data
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 666, in __str__
    return self.__bytes__()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 676, in __bytes__
    return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 691, in __unicode__
    fits_horizontal = self._repr_fits_horizontal_()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 651, in _repr_fits_horizontal_
    d.to_string(buf=buf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1488, in to_string
    formatter.to_string()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 314, in to_string
    strcols = self._to_str_columns()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 258, in _to_str_columns
    str_index = self._get_formatted_index()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 472, in _get_formatted_index
    fmt_index = [index.format(name=show_index_names, formatter=fmt)]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 450, in format
    return self._format_with_header(header, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 472, in _format_with_header
    result = _trim_front(format_array(values, None, justify='left'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 1321, in format_array
    return fmt_obj.get_result()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 1448, in get_result
return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 1495, in _make_fixed_width
    max_len = np.max([_strlen(x) for x in strings])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 184, in _strlen
    return len(x.decode(encoding))
LookupError: unknown encoding: MS874
```

I have tried to run this in IPython, and it does not give the error, so I think the problem is with my Eclipse setting. I use Eclipse Juno and I installed Pandas via Python(x,y).

I have tried to solve it blindly like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('foo.csv');
b = True;
while(b):
    try:
        print data
        b = False
    except:
        print 'foooo'
```

And it just printed `'foooo'` forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Right click on the project => Properties => Resource => Text file encoding. Choose other => UTF-8.